# SAP Cloud SDK Spring Security JARS

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I have an SAP Cloud SDk Project and currently I am using version "0.27.2" for security commons dependency as shown below:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sap.xs2.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>security-commons</artifactId>
        <version>0.27.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

While doing integration tests, am getting an dependency error as below:

[WARNING] The POM for com.sap.xs2.security:security-commons:jar:0.28.6 is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for com.sap.xs2.security:java-container-security:jar:0.28.6 is missing, no dependency information available

Due to the above, I am not able to run the integration test scripts. Also, I tried to get the versions from the SAP Support portal as shown .But I am unable to find which package will get me the 0.28.6 version? Please help me getting the correct version?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct version to use is `XS_JAVAP_2-70001362.ZIP` which is actually *not* the latest one. Since the version is specified by the SDK you don't need to provide a version number in your pom.

I hope this solves the problem. If not, please expand your question to contain the version of the SDK that you are using and also your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Let me check and will let u know.Thanks Mat

Comment: I double checked again and corrected my answer since the above mentioned is actually *not* the latest version. Sorry for the confusion. I also double checked that the ZIP actually contains the `28.6` version used by the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that in case you are using Spring Boot, there is also a spring boot starter available: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-security-xsuaa-integration/tree/master/spring-xsuaa